# Batch update does not works when using JPQL

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, jpql

I'm trying to add a batch update to my spring boot project. But multiple queries are still executed when I check SQL logs and Hibernate stats.

**Hibernate stats**

```
290850400 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
3347700 nanoseconds spent preparing 19 JDBC statements;
5919028800 nanoseconds spent executing 19 JDBC statements;
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
2635900 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 1 entities and 0 collections);
19447300 nanoseconds spent executing 19 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 18 entities and 18 collections)
```

**Versions**

```
Spring Boot v2.7.1 
Spring v5.3.21
Java 17.0.3.1
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/db
    username: user
    password: password
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
    hibernate:
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
        format_sql: false
        jdbc:
          fetch_size: 100
          batch_size: 5
        order_updates: true
        batch_versioned_data: true
        generate_statistics: true
```

**Snapshot entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SNAPSHOT", schema = "SYSTEM", catalog = "")
public class Snapshot {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "CREATED_ON")
    private String createdOn;
    ...
}
```

**SnapshotRepository**

```
@Repository
public interface SnapshotRepository extends JpaRepository<Snapshot, Long> {

    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE Snapshot s SET s.fieldValue =?1,s.createdOn=?2 where s.id = ?3 and s.fieldName = ?4")
    int updateSnapshot(String fieldValue, String createdOn, String id, String fieldName);
}
```

And this repository method is called from the service class.

```
  for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : res.getValues().entrySet()) {
      snapshotRepository.updateSnapshot(entry.getValue(), createdOn, id, entry.getKey());
  }
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc11</artifactId>
    <version>21.7.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

In the `application.yml`, I think I'm configuring all required properties to activate batch update but still no luck.

Please let me know what I'm doing incorrectly.

Comment: try setting hibernate.jdbc.batch_size also in hibernate.properties

Comment: @p3consulting I did, but nothing changed.

Comment: "batch settings" influence on session `flush` behaviour, in your case `@Query("UPDATE ...` performs direct updates in DB. Perhaps, you are modifying entities in memory, which forces HBN to flush their state prior issuing SQL update.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov yes, you are right, I already tested, and the configuration is working fine. I tried to select an entity from DB, update its values, and save it using `snapshotRepository.save(snapshot)` The batching works perfectly in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Batching only works when Hibernate does the flushing of entities. If you are executing manual queries, Hibernate can't do batching.

The way you are implementing this, Hibernate will reuse the same prepared statement on the database side though, but no JDBC batching.